# Work Item Description Height Not Increasing

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am wanting to update some of our TFS work items as users have reported that in the Web Access portal there is a lot of wasted space.

What I mean is when we load a work item, and there is as Description text box (type HtmlFieldControl, refname System.Description) then there appears to be a lot of white space between the control and the bottom of the page.   When I open the work item in Visual Studio, then it appears fine and the Description fills up correctly.
Altering the Height property just doesn't seem to change how it renders in a browser.

```
<TabGroup>
      <Tab Label="Description">
        <Control FieldName="System.Description" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="Des&amp;cription:" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" Height="500"/>
      </Tab>
.... Other tabs here
</TabGroup>
```

Whilst typing this up I realised it is probably a bit tough to get what I mean, so I've taken a screenshot.   I just can't get the Description field to increase in visible height when viewed in a browser.

Hopefully this makes sense.

EDIT: I have found a link where a user is reporting the same problem, unfortunately the idea posted about changing the MinimumSize didn't help that user or me.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3afca41-a09b-4ccf-bd76-e32145d7fc13/minimumsize-attribute-not-working-with-htmlfieldcontrol-for-tfs-2012?forum=tfsworkitemtracking

[image: Work item in a browser]

Comment: I think the overall form height comes from the tallest tab? Do History, Links, File Attachments or Details reach to the bottom of the form?

Comment: They are basically all the same, I can't remember the history tab so I'll have to check tomorrow but the others are basically identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to determine this now doesn't seem possible in TFS 2012, there appears to be a bug around the resizing of an HTMLFieldControl.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1148630/issues-with-htmlfieldcontrol-and-tfs-2012-tfs-2013-web-accesss

Description

> I have recently upgraded from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012.4 and have noticed
>   some issues with the HTMLFieldControl and TWA 2012.
>   1.The MinimumSize attribute does not work in Team Web Access.  It defaults to a specific size (250 pixels).

Response

> Thank you reporting the issue. The problem with MinSize will be fixed
>   in the TFS 2015.

I won't accept this immediately as I hope there is an alternative solution, but there seems to be no other option to resolve my issue.

Comment: TFS2015 here. Height is still static, but at lease MinimumSize works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "**Minimumsize**" like following:

```
<Control FieldName="System.Description" Type="HtmlFieldControl" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" MinimumSize="(0,700)" />
```

And I recommend you to use [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to edit the work item definitions as you can preview the changes with it.
[image]

Comment: I shall try minimum size shortly. I already have TFS power tools, as I mentioned in my post checking work items in visual studio is fine - its only in a web browser that they appear this way.

Comment: @MattR The change should apply to the display in browser. It works at my side. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, there was no change, unless the page is cached.  I know there was a reset cache option in the TFS 2010 website, but nothing in 2012, either way the preview looks fine but the page is exactly the same.

Comment: @MattR I just change and save the Minimum Size value. And then reopen the web page from browser, the size is changed based on the value.

Comment: OK, still no joy though.   The preview updates as expected, the actual view in a web browser remains static.