# TFS Work Item Form 100% Height

Tags: tfs, workitem

In TFS web interface, is it possible to force a Work Item Form layout to fill 100% height? For example:  [image]

Would it be possible in the WIT definition to make it so the tab fills the full height of the form when the form is expanded? There's an option for width to be 100%, but not sure if possible for height.

Comment: Any update on this issue,  did my reply worked? There is no any other way to auto fill 100% height. You could only change the height value of Minimumsize.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "**Minimumsize**" like following:

```
<Control FieldName="System.Description" Type="HtmlFieldControl" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" MinimumSize="(0,465)" />
```

> And you could also use [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to edit the work item
>   definitions as you can preview the changes with it.

More details and screenshot please refer *Eddie's* answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35217601/5391065), the value of height as below should be 465.

[image: The value =465]

---

Besides, there is a **Maximize** button in the right top corner

[image]

After click it, the tab will expand and fills both 100 height and width.
[image]